# Try and Except Function to be implemented in Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

i am extracting the Group Id from internal site.

The URL it takes from csv file which is located in my desktop.

The below code currently extracts Group ID without any problem until and unless the URL is valid.

But i want to run this code till the end even though there is invalid URLs in the csv file also it should say "invalid url" in my output xls file located in the desktop

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

c=1

user = os.getlogin()
path = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/groupid.csv"
path1 = "C:/Users/"+user+"/Desktop/groupid.xlsx"
print(path)

reader = pd.read_csv(path)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

reader['groupid'] = ''
for line in reader['URL']:
    print(line)
    driver.get(line)
    if c==1:
        time.sleep(60)

    time.sleep(5)
    groupid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Xpath"]').text
    print(groupid)
    reader['groupid'][reader['URL']==line] = groupid
    c=c+1    
reader.to_excel(path1)
print("extraction Complete")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I'm not very familiar with pandas. If you want an "invalid URL" column, can you not use the same approach that you're using for "groupid"?

```
reader['invalid_url'] = 'No'
reader['groupid'] = ''
for line in reader['URL']:
    try:
        driver.get(line)
    except WhateverExceptionYouNeedToHandle:
        reader['invalid_url'][reader['URL']==line] = 'Yes'
        c += 1
        continue
    ...
```

Comment: Thank You @hmm, it works but it does not write the output in the excel. Please help

Comment: Can someone help on this.

Comment: @kumaranT I'm not sure what doesn't work, but see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not tell which error is being raised and at which point, it is hard to tell you what you should do.

But I will assume that you face a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) raised by Selenium:

```py
for line in reader['URL']:
    print(line)
    driver.get(line)

    # ...

    try:
        groupid = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="Xpath"]'
        ).text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Could not find element by xpath. Maybe a bad URL?")
        c += 1
        # Tell python to go to next element in loop
        continue

    print(groupid)
    # ...
```